# AWS CodeDeploy with cross account S3 access fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, aws-code-deploy

I have my build artifacts in an S3 bucket in my dev account. I have an EC2 instance (target of deployment) and CodeDeploy setup in the prod account. Both instance profile role and CodeDeployRole have access to the bucket in dev account. From instance I can manually copy the files.

However deployment fails during download bundle phase with access denied.

Please help.

Bucket policy in dev account:

````
"Principal": {
"AWS": [
"arn:aws:iam:: 222222222222:role/CodeDeployRole",
"arn:aws:iam:: 222222222222:role/instanceprofilerole"
]
},
"Action": [
"s3:PutObject",
"s3:ListBucket",
"s3:GetObject",
"s3:Get*",
"s3:List*"
],
"Resource": [
"arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname",
"arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname/*"```
````

Comment: Stages in CodePipeline use a KMS key to encrypt artifacts in S3 as they're passed from one stage to another. Which KMS key are you using? Which account is the key in — dev or prod? Wherever the key is, the other account should have permissions to use it.

Comment: Hi Harish, I'm not even using CodePipeline. For the time being I'm setting up build and deploy manually. So there is no KMS.

Comment: Ensure that `CodeDeployRole` & `instanceprofilerole` include S3 permissions. If that isn't the issue, try setting `Action` to `s3:*` in bucket policy temporarily.

Comment: Please paste the 'CodeDeployRole' permissions in your question.

Comment: AmazonEC2RoleforAWSCodeDeploy + AmazonS3FullAccess + AWSCodeDeployRole + AWSCodeDeployForLambda